# Where to start to learning Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am new to the Mojo framework... I went through some of the wiki pages on the [Mojolicious website](http://mojolicio.us), however couldn't comprehend many things. The documentation seemed to be for someone who already has a background with the Mojo framework.

So, I'm wondering whether there is any place for a newbie to start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the mojocasts cited by tempire are a good start, I find the docs a bit fragmentary, and prefer
to dig the code of other projects...
Here you can find some code to read here
https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Example-applications
This one is pretty good:
https://github.com/tempire/MojoExample

Answer (score 6):

The wiki isn't necessarily trustworthy, since anyone can change it, and it isn't always up to date.

Start with the mojocasts at http://mojocasts.com; then move on to the docs.

The docs are accessible for new users; just make sure you read the guides in the order they are listed on http://mojolicio.us/perldoc.